# Zoom level lost in public visualization?

Tags: visualisation, carto

I've got a visualization made where in the back-end it looks great. zoom level = 5.  Then any method of publishing sets the zoom level to 3.
Can this be forced to remain 5?

strangely, this other simple test map doesn't even have a zoom parameter passed to the url. This was the embed url I picked up on the day I was messing with it.
http://highrank.robh71.com/map1/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, the iframe are zoom/centered by a bounding box, not centroid and zoom actually. You can see it in the iframe URL of the map you linked to, this part,

```
&sw_lat=28.98411731593083&sw_lon=-456.39404296875&ne_lat=30.15462722077597&ne_lon=-453.75732421875
```

I believe you can override it by replacing it instead with a center_lat, center_lon, and zoom,

```
&center_lat=28.98411731593083&center_lon=-456.39404296875&zoom=2
```

I'm guessing, the reason why the lon is so far negative is because you are zoomed in on a wrapped version of the map. Add your own though, it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew!  I'd been forcing it already with zoom=X.  My client didn't believe that this was how to do it but now he's implemented the map as such.  He wanted it to maintain in the shortened URL but the lack of control there is obvious.  Thanks again :)